# Finding the Index with maximum number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

**My task:**

For the next set of questions, we will be using census data from the [United States Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/). Counties are political and geographic subdivisions of states in the United States. This dataset contains population data for counties and states in the US from 2010 to 2015. [See this document](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/technical-documentation/file-layouts/2010-2015/co-est2015-alldata.pdf) for a description of the variable names.

The census dataset (census.csv) should be loaded as census_df. Answer questions using this as appropriate.

**Question 5**

Which state has the most counties in it? (hint: consider the `sumlevel` key carefully! You'll need this for future questions too...)

*This function should return a single string value.*

```py
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
census_df = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV']==50]
census_df_2 = census_df.groupby(by='STNAME',axis=0)
```

This, however, does **not** group the DataFrame by `'STNAME'`, which can be seen when executing `census_df_2.head()`

I suppose this should work on a grouped DataFrame:

```py
def answer_five():
    return census_df_2[ census_df_2['COUNTY'].count() == max( census_df_2['COUNTY'].count() ) ].index().tolist()[0]
answer_five()
```

**Why does the groupby function not work?** I've tried changing the axis and using the `set_index()` function instead but I can't get it to work.

If someone knows another way to solve this problem I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Ah, this sounds very much like a homework or training question. You even pasted the hint :-) What do you mean by, the group does not work? Have you already tried to apply aggregate? e.g. something like census_df.groupby(by='STNAME').aggregate({'county': 'nunique'})

Comment: The grouping does something strange. When I do `census_df_2.groupby('STNAME').head()` it doesn't return the first five elements grouped by state name but the original dataframe by index but only indexes 1-5, 69-73,99-103,115-119, ... 3170-3174, seemingly choosing indexes randomly. I haven't tried that although I did use .agg at some point unsuccessfully. Why is the function nunique in ' '?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` simply returns a groupby object, you'll have to specify an aggregate function to be used on this object, e.g.

```
df.groupby(by='STNAME').aggregate({'COUNTY': 'nunique'}).idxmax()[0]
```

gives

```
'Texas'
```

See [the pandas docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) for an introduction to grouping/aggregating.

Comment: Thank you. I just figured out the solution like this, although I don't know why groupby was acting weird earlier: census_df.groupby('STNAME').count()['COUNTY'].idxmax()