# How to count a row with the most elements in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an assignment where I have to count the amount of counties there are per state and display the county with the most states in a dataframe that looks as follows:

```py
X = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "SUMLEV": [40, 50, 50, 50, 50],
    "REGION": [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    "DIVISION": [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
    "STATE": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "COUNTY": [0, 1, 3, 5, 7],
    "STNAME": ["Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama"],
    "CTYNAME": ["Alabama", "Autauga County", "Baldwin County", "Barbour County", "Bibb County"]
})

>>> X
   SUMLEV  REGION  DIVISION  STATE  COUNTY   STNAME         CTYNAME
0      40       3         6      1       0  Alabama         Alabama
1      50       3         6      1       1  Alabama  Autauga County
2      50       3         6      1       3  Alabama  Baldwin County
3      50       3         6      1       5  Alabama  Barbour County
4      50       3         6      1       7  Alabama     Bibb County
```

Up until this point I reconed I would just sort the dataframe according to STNAME and then according to CTYNAME. Thereafter I planned to count the amount of rows in each county, but I am unsure how to do that.
This is what I have so far

```
def answer_five() :
    census_df = df[df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
    census_df.groupby(['STNAME'])
    census_df.groupby([CTYNAME])
```

Comment: Hey just FYI, it's always preferred that you include code that makes your question/problem reproducible. Attaching screenshots of data and/or dataframes like this makes it difficult for other users to reproduce your problem. Just a heads up since it's your first question :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56884272/6361531

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
X.groupby("STNAME")["COUNTY"].nunique().idxmax()
```

This would first group your data by the name of the state `STNAME`, so now you're analyzing at the state level. Then, you look at the counties only (per state), by grabbing the `"COUNTY"` column, and then count the number of unique counties *per state* (`nunique()`). Finally, you want the state with the maximum number of counties, so `idxmax()` will give you the index (in this case, as it's the result of a groupby, it will be the state name), of the row with the highest value.

Comment: Nice explanation for the code. Well done!

Comment: X[(X.SUMLEV==50)].groupby("STNAME")['COUNTY'].sum().idxmax()